# Pipette brightens the color in texture painter - Blender 2.8 Beta

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Pipette brightens the color in texture painter.

How to replicate:

- Go into texture paint mode.
- Select fill tool.
- Select a color e.g.: R: 0.250 G: 0.150 B: 0.070.
- Select Blend mode Mix.
- Fill the mesh.
- Go back to fill tool, click the color and click the Pipette.
- Pipette your colored texture and it will become a brighter color e.g: R: 0.277 G: 0.156 B: 0.071.
- When filling with this brighter color it visibly brightens the texture, and when using pipette again it increases in brightness again.

I was expecting it to retain the same color (R: 0.250 G: 0.150 B: 0.070).

Before pic:

[image: R: 0.250 G: 0.150 B: 0.070]

After pic:

[image: R: 0.277 G: 0.156 B: 0.071]

Is this a bug or am I using an incorrect mode?

Comment: Not sure if it is a bug, but you are using 2.8 so that is a possibility. Have you set the sampling method to 'combined' in the tool popup in screen? I'd be curious to see if that has an effect on your color sample then.

Comment: Hi Craig thanks for commenting, I'm relatively new to blender and couldn't find the tool popup (i'm not sure what i'm looking for, my googling came up short). Also, I noticed that the pipette color is different if I select the same color in the texture view vs the object view. It doesn't appear to take the raw color from the texture, I have tried all the color space options, which all changes the pipette result but none give the correct color. Photoshop finds the correct color however. This issue persists between all of the painting tools, when using the pipette.

Comment: In texture paint in the 3d view, if you sample the color you should see a little rectangle there in the 3d view and if you press the arrow to open it up, you see the last operator options and there you will see 'combined'.